# CYPRESS- error during type a value from API request to input

Tags: javascript, api, cypress, one-time-password, dom-element

When I  try to type OTP code (I get it from API), cypress shows an error [cypress screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxOcd.png)

```
 cy.get('input[data-placeholder="OTP"]').type(getOtpCode(phoneNumber))
```

```html
function getOtpCode(phone) {
  var otpCode;
  cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'url'
  }).then(resp => resp.body)
    .then(data => data.find(element => element['body']['Message']['Phone'] == phone))
    .then(phone => otpCode = phone['body']['Message']['CustomMessage']);
  return otpCode;
}
```

If i typed a random string instead getOtpCode() it's working.
Do you know how to resolve that problem?
Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the function do this:

```js
cy.get('input[data-placeholder="OTP"]')
  .should('be.visible')
  .type(getOtpCode(phoneNumber))

function getOtpCode(phone) {
  var otpCode
  cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'url',
  })
    .then((resp) => resp.body)
    .then((data) =>
      data.find((element) => element['body']['Message']['Phone'] == phone)
    )
    .then((phone) => (otpCode = phone['body']['Message']['CustomMessage']))
  return cy.wrap(otpCode)
}
```

In your test file do this:

```js
import className from '../path-to-js-file.js' //replace className with yours
const obj = new className() //replace className with yours

describe('Test Suite', () => {
  it('Test Case', () => {
    obj.getOtpCode(phone).then((otp) => {
      cy.get('input[data-placeholder="OTP"]').type(otp)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists.
'cy.type() failed because it requires a DOM element.

The subject received was:

  > 817968

The previous command that ran was:

  > cy.then()'

Comment: Can you add the code for `getOtpCode`.

Comment: I added to my question :)

Comment: Where is this function written, in a separate js file.

Comment: yes, I export function from another js file :)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you need to perform `getOtpCode()` first, because of the async `cy.request()`.

Also the function needs to return the `cy.request()` to allow `.then()` to be used after it.

```js
function getOtpCode(phone) {
  return cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'url'
  })
  .then(resp => resp.body)
  .then(data => data.find(element => element['body']['Message']['Phone'] == phone))
  .then(phone => phone['body']['Message']['CustomMessage']);
}

getOtpCode(phoneNumber).then(otpcode => {
  cy.get('input[data-placeholder="OTP"]').type(otpcode)
})
```

---

Alternately, change the function to a custom command. You will not need to return anything as Cypress sets the current subject to the result of the last `.then()` in the  `cy.request()` chain.

The custom command can be defined globally.

**cypress/support/commands.js**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getOtpCode', (phone) => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'url'
  })
  .then(resp => resp.body)
  .then(data => data.find(element => element['body']['Message']['Phone'] == phone))
  .then(phone => phone['body']['Message']['CustomMessage']);
})
```

**test**

```js
cy.getOtpCode(phoneNumber).then(otpcode => {
  cy.get('input[data-placeholder="OTP"]').type(otpcode)
})
```